# How to accept an ascii character with python re (regex)

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

I have a regex that controls a password so that it contains an upper case, a lower case, a number, a special character and minimum 8 characters.

regex is:

```py
regex_password = r"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\W]).{8,}$"
```

I use in this function:

```py
def password_validator(password):
    #REGEX PASSWORD : minimum 8 characters, 1 lowercase, 1 uppercase, 1 special caracter
    regex_password = r"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\W]).{8,}$"

    if not re.match(regex_password, password):
        raise ValueError("""value is not a valid password""")
    return password
```

However, the use of "²" raises me an error, however, this same regex with a Javascript front-end validation, or on different regex validation site,works.

The problem is possible the ascii, so how can i do for python accept the ascii character in regex ?

Comment: For what it's worth, `\W` is already a character class, so the square brackets around it are superfluous.

Comment: The `²` char is from the `\p{No}` class. Most regex engines only match `\p{Nd}` with `\w`, but not in Python. Hence, `\W` does not match superscript numbers in `re`. In JavaScript, `\w` only matches `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, so in Python 3, you can make the `\w` ASCII only aware with `re.A`.

Comment: You could try `[\W²]` to include it or alternatively, you can use the `\S` character set, which matches any non-whitespace character, to include the `²` character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-35):

> `\W`

> Matches any character which is not a word character. This is the opposite of `\w`. If the `ASCII` flag is used this becomes the equivalent of `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`. If the `LOCALE` flag is used, matches characters which are neither alphanumeric in the current locale nor the underscore.

Other implementations may interpret `\w` as referring to only ASCII alphanumeric characters and underscore by default and `\W` by extension contains every non-ASCII alphanumeric characters as well as non-alphanumeric characters.

Possible solutions:

Spell it out:

```
regex_password = r"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9_]).{8,}$"
```

Or use the `re.ASCII` flag:

```
if not re.match(regex_password, password, flags=re.ASCII):
```

Either one of these changes should give you the results you need.